# GLTFLoader doesn't feed the property 'bones' of geometry in SkinnedMesh

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm using export and load function from Blender to Three.js. I'm currently moving from json to gltf2 to do so. But with the gltf export/load there are Geometry.skeleton.bones but Geometry.bones are no longer populated. I look for help, how can they be restored from the skeleton ?

Comment: Could you include a link to your `.blend` model? And, which of the glTF Blender exporters are you using?

Comment: here is the .blend with related jpg http://lu-e-lou.com/priv/proust.zip ; I managed to export the object with material and animations but just geometry.bones is missing

Comment: and the exporters I'm using is io_scene_gltf2 : Import-Export: glTF 2.0 format - Author Norbert Nopper. Don't know if there is a release # ?

Comment: Hm, I don't think `geometry.bones` is anywhere in three.js documentation, maybe only JSON uses it? But `mesh.skeleton.bones` should work correctly without that — is something not working as expected? Try opening your file in http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and opening the JS console - the bones are loaded OK, just not as children of the meshes.

Comment: Right ; but as it was there with the JSON loader my piece of sofware uses it for UI purposes. Actually my software is a general graphical tool for developping scene (and movies) within this tool. Many 3D objects are in a library and composing a scene is done graphically by selecting objects in the library. A number of tools are proposed for managing animations and including videos.

Comment: The tool is on line and is open to all at lu-e-lou.fr ;  So, I understand the problem is now on my side ; I have tu update my platform to adapt to this and I was thinking the mesh.bones structure can be rebuilt from the skeleton.bones. But perhaps is it better to just change the related functions to use the skeleton.bones structure.  I'll will work on this and thank you for this clarification which helps me going into the right direction.

Comment: I updated my code but observe one pb : the human body and the cloth (red apron) are 2 meshes which I join (ctrl J) after having transfered weights data from body to cloth. After gltf export, the weights are no longer allocated to the cloth in the export. So body moves its legs but cross the apron.

Comment: Does it seem like the Blender exporter is not writing vertex weights for one of your meshes? If so I would file a bug on the exporter.

Comment: OK thanks ; I checked and weights for the apron mesh are all 0.